# CF ORM: Filter data using composite/FK

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I was having difficulty in filtering a table tab1 which had a FK key from tab2 (tab1 had many to one relation with tab2) using ORM.I wanted to filter data in tab1 using the fk column. so I used 
     var items= entityLoad("tab1",{fk_col_name=value_variable}).

Now I was getting the error: You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class
java.lang.String as a structure with members.

Let me share my solution below but if there are any better alternatives please share.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was paved way through lot googling as usual. It seems this is because entityLoad() is a convenience function that only works against defined properties.  To entityLoad(), breedid is not a property.  Instead, Breed is the property, being of type Breed.  To get around this we can use HQL instead.

So

Ref: http://blog.nictunney.com/2011/02/coldfusion-orm-filtering-on-composite.html